# Probability of red M&Ms

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume that red M&Ms are 10% of all M&Ms. There are 18 M&Ms in a pack. Each pack is a random sample of the population of M&Ms.

1. What is the probability of a pack with no red M&Ms?
2. What is the probability of a pack with all red M&Ms?
3. What is the probability of a pack with one red M&M?
4. What sampling distribution are you using?

#### Progress

This is what I have gotten so far:
a. $(9/10)^{18} \approx 0.15$
b. $(1/10)^{18} = 10^{-18}$
c. This is where I'm unsure of where to go.

Comment: What did you get so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: This is what I have gotten so far:

a. (9/10)^18 ~~ 0.15 

b. (1/10)^18 = 10^-18 

c. This is where I'm unsure of where to go.

Comment: Your answers on $1$ and $2$ are okay. Do you know the answer on $4$? If so then you can solve $3$ as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to answer (d) first:  It is Bernoulli, with $p = 0.1$.

Then your course has covered the relation between Bernoulli variates and binomial coefficients:

$$
P(n \mbox{ red }) \binom{18}{n}p^n (1-p)^{18-n}
$$
where $\binom{18}{n}$ is the number of ways to choose $n$ objects ourt of a given $18$.

So for exanble, the answer to (c) is
$$
P(1 \mbox{ red }) \binom{18}{1}(0.1)(0.9)^{17} = 18 (0.1)(0.9)^{17}
$$

Comment: That is where I was leading towards. Through the equation, I got ~ 0.30 = 30%.  Thank you for your help. It is greatly appreciated.